# Can not format pubDate to NSDate iOS

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I can not figure out why NSDate continues to throw nil.

```
NSString * copyString = [[self.parseResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"date"];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:copyString];

NSLog(@"%@", copyString);
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Did I set the date format set properly?

> Output from copyString
>
> 2014-01-24 11:17:25.893 Events[32755:70b] Wed, 31 Dec 1969 16:00:00
>   PST
>
> 2014-01-24 11:17:25.895 Events[32755:70b] Fri, 24 Jan 2014 20:00:00
>   PST
>
> 2014-01-24 11:17:25.896 Events[32755:70b] Sat, 25 Jan 2014 10:00:00
>   PST
>
> 2014-01-24 11:17:25.897 Events[32755:70b] Mon, 27 Jan 2014 10:00:00
>   PST
>
> 2014-01-24 11:17:25.899 Events[32755:70b] Mon, 27 Jan 2014 12:15:00
>   PST
>
> 2014-01-24 11:17:25.900 Events[32755:70b] Mon, 27 Jan 2014 19:00:00
>   PST
>
> Output from date
>
> 2014-01-24 11:22:24.707 Events[32827:70b] (null)
>
> 2014-01-24 11:22:24.709 Events[32827:70b] (null)
>
> 2014-01-24 11:22:24.710 Events[32827:70b] (null)
>
> 2014-01-24 11:22:24.712 Events[32827:70b] (null)
>
> 2014-01-24 11:22:24.713 Events[32827:70b] (null)
>
> 2014-01-24 11:22:24.714 Events[32827:70b] (null)

Comment: Is the iOS device or simulator running this code set to English? Are you sure there is no hidden whitespace/newlines at the end of `copyString`?

Comment: 1) NSDateFormatter often has trouble with a leading day-of-week -- usually better to strip it off.  2) You will also have trouble if the locale and device settings are in conflict re 12/24 hour presentation.  Best to use "en_US_POSIX" as the locale to circumvent this.

Comment: Did you set the Locale/TimeZone?

Comment: In my computer it works, check you locale.

Comment: NSString * copyString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[self.parseResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"date"]];
    NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [df setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    [df setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
    
    NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:copyString];
 
    NSLog(@"%@",date);

Comment: I set the NSLocale to en_US_POSIX but still its printing null